# Constraint in Oracle that depends on the value of a field

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Imagine I have a table in an Oracle database with 3 columns, `ID` (PK), `NAME` and `ACTIVE`. If I wanted, for example, to have `NAME` and `ACTIVE` be unique together, I could easily do that. However, what I want is for `NAME` to be unique only when `ACTIVE` in that row is set to true (1). When `ACTIVE` is false (0), I want to be able to have an arbitrary number of rows with the same `NAME` (but different `ID`, of course). Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in Oracle you can create a unique index with a `CASE` statement, in your case something like;

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_uq ON test(
  name, 
  CASE WHEN active = 0 THEN id ELSE 0 END
)
```

Since id is unique, we can have multiple rows with the same name as long as active=0 (since the uniqueness will be based on the (name,id)), while an active entry will check uniqueness on (name,0) which allows only a single active row per name.

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/34d76a/1). Try to add a duplicate active entry, and it will not insert.

Answer (score 4):

Here another possibility.

`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_uq ON test(decode(active,1,name,null))`

With that, your index is the smallest possible because you don't need to index inactive values. It couls be usefull if your table began to be very big with juste small active values